# botoes alinhamento como fazer

Tags: html, bootstrap

Pessoal os botoes estao desalinhado o que posso fazer estou usando o bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/a6Lt5Lgx/10/

```
<div class="container">
    <form  name="materia" method="post" action="cad_Materia.php">
        <div class="form-group" >
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Disciplina:</td>
                    <td><input class="form-control"  placeholder="Informe a diciplina" name="disciplina" type="text" required x-moz-errormessage="Disciplina não informada."></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Carga Horaria:</td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="Informe a carga horaria" name="cargaHoraria" type="text" required x-moz-errormessage="Carga Horario não informada." ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bibliografia:</td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="Informe a bibliografia " name="bibliografia" type="text" required x-moz-errormessage="Bibliografia não informada." ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Codigo:</td>
                    <td><input class="form-control" placeholder="Informe o codigo " name="codigoMat" type="text" required x-moz-errormessage="Codigo não informada."></td>
                </tr>
                </div>

                <div class="btn-group"> 

                        <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="cadastrar"></td> 
                        <td><input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Alterar" style="width: 86px; height: 34px" onclick="action='alt_Materia.php'" title="Informe (Disciplina/Carga Horaria/bibliografia) a Alterar e (Codigo) cadastrado"/></td>
                        <td><input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Deletar" style="width: 86px; height: 34px"  onclick="action='del_Materia.php'" title="Informe (Disciplina/Codigo) e clique aqui"/></td>

                </div>
            </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Não duplique perguntas, sane os problemas indicados na original sempre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está afastado devido ao formato da tabela criada ,
`<table>`. Você adicionou uma terceira coluna que ficou alinhada após as caixas de texto. As colunas, abrimos com a tag `<td>`.

Eu coloquei o botão deletar na mesma coluna do botão Alterar, apenas para ilustrar por enquanto, retirando as tags `<td>` e `</td>` nessa parte do código:

```
    <td><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="cadastrar"></td> 
    <td><input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit" value="Alterar" style="width: 86px; height: 34px" onclick="action='alt_Materia.php'" title="Informe (Disciplina/Carga Horaria/bibliografia) a Alterar e (Codigo) cadastrado"/><!--Retirei a tag </td> daqui-->
    <!--Retirei a tag <td> daqui--><input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Deletar" style="width: 86px; height: 34px"  onclick="action='del_Materia.php'" title="Informe (Disciplina/Codigo) e clique aqui"/></td>
```

Atualizei seu html aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/a6Lt5Lgx/16/

Comment: Sugiro a leitura [deste link](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/846/sauda%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e-agradecimentos)

Comment: Danilo, por favor visite o link acima, ele justifica porque estou removendo saudações e agradecimentos.

Comment: Entendido! @diegofm